# How to clone with git extension?

Tags: git, ssh, git-extensions

I need create clone repository.

but I do not know where can I get ssh key file

[image]

[image]

Update: 
git clone test@source.elasticgit.com:myrepo.git - worked!  Why not get a extension?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `git clone`, Git will remove the `.git` extension if the clone is not bare (e.g. it has a working copy), which is the default.